# MVC SqlServer Database login fail

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm currently on a MVC platform using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, whenever I try to connect to the database this happens

```
PM> Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=DB;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "DB" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'PC'.
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, TableSelectionSet tableSelectionSet)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, TableSelectionSet tableSelectionSet)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.SqlServerScaffoldingModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, TableSelectionSet tableSelectionSet)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineeringGenerator.GetMetadataModel(ReverseEngineeringConfiguration configuration)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineeringGenerator.GenerateAsync(ReverseEngineeringConfiguration configuration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContextAsync(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.d__22.MoveNext()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source, Int32& length)
>      at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`1.b__0()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
>   ClientConnectionId:39d773a8-7fba-451b-b86b-d48b481cfe9a
>   Error Number:4060,State:1,Class:11
>   Cannot open database "FacilityDB1" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'PC'.**

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you running your application through IIS or IIS Express, try to host it in ISS and in Application pool under which your application is running, change  Application Identity to the user you want "I suppose it PC as per your question". also make sure you give access to this user in your database from SQL server itself, if you want me to write more desc as an answer I can do that for you, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be happened cause you might not have a user named `PC` or did not assign access privileges to your user `PC` in database

1) Make sure you add the user to your SQL server database and give it also user access to your database.

2) Also run your application in `IIS` under the same user  "PC in your case" and make sure you type the **correct password** for it. you can change it from "Application Pools" Choose your pool under which your application is currently running and from "Application Identity" change your user to be the same as the one you created before (step 1) "`PC` in your case"

Please leave a comment if it did not work and I would be happy to update my answer

Comment: Thanks for helping but the user was originally given access to my database, as for the 2nd option, can you please elaborate more on it? Sorry I just started out not long ago so I don't really know alot of things. Edit: My other databases using the same localdb work fine except for this